# Which is proper in this sentence: ‘assurance’ or ‘assurances’

Tags: nouns

> Then suddenly, despite all their ______ (assurance/ assurances), they broke the agreement and signed a deal with a rival company.

I’m not sure which form of the word ‘assurance’ should be taken in this sentence. I think the word assurance itself means ‘promise’ here, but not ‘ confidence’ , and according to the dictionary it’s a countable noun. But our teacher provides us with the answer ‘assurance’ the single one. Is the answer wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The same word can have different meanings.  It is often the case that with one of the meanings the word is countable, and with the other, not.

If you can put "a" or "an" in front of the noun *for the meaning in question*, it is always safe to use the plural with **all**

We can give someone "*an* assurance", that is, a guarantee or promise, so:

> ... despite all their **assurances** <sup>(i.e. promises)</sup> , they reneged
>
> ... The lawyers filed many **pleadings** <sup>(i.e. legal motions, submissions)</sup>  seeking damages, but despite all their pleadings, their client did not receive a penny.

When an article is not used (with the particular meaning in question) use the singular:

> ... despite all her **assurance** <sup>(i.e. self-confidence)</sup> she felt ill-at-ease in front of a large crowd
>
> ... despite all their **pleading** <sup>(i.e. imploring, begging)</sup>  they were sent to bed with no TV

Comment: I wouldn’t write off “despite all their assurance”. *Assurance* is uncountable rather than singular there.

Comment: @Lawrence: I wouldn't write it off completely, but  it normally is countable when the meaning is "guarantee" or "promise" (as in OP's example) and uncountable when it means confidence in one's own abilities.

Comment: So... assurance here means ‘promise’ and I should use its plural, right?

Comment: Sorry to bother again... what do you mean by‘ (with the particular meaning in question) ’in your answer？

Comment: Your rules are self-contradictory. Based on your first sentence, it should be *all their pleadings* and *all her assurances*. However, you've used the singular. Either your first sentence is wrong or your final two examples are wrong.

Comment: @Jason Bassford. You've misunderstood the rule, dude.  When someone implores us to do something, that kind of **pleading** is non-count.  But a lawyer's submissions to a court, those **pleadings** are countable.  We don't use an article with "implore" pleading and we do use an article with the lawyer's pleading.

Comment: @Ivie:  The same word can have different meanings, and with one of those meanings it can be countable and with the other not.

Comment: @Ivie: So yes, if it means "promises" in your context, use the plural.

Comment: @TRomano This is better—but it's still a little confusing. First, you should use *despite all their assurance* in the second example so that you are comparing apples to apples. As it reads, there's an implication that it's *their* and *her* that are making the difference. But that's not the case—and you're changing two things at once. I would remove your second paragraph (because the mention of the indefinite articles is confusing in relation to the examples), and I would do your superscript thing after the first example of *assurances* instead, with *(i.e. guarantees, promises*).

Comment: Also, I would say *When an article can be used or the noun counted* in the first introduction and *when an article cannot be used and the noun cannot be counted* in the second. The *an* in the third paragraph is again at odds with the example given, which doesn't actually use it.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: I agree with your remark that for the sake of clarity the superscript annotations should be used in the first examples as well, and I've now done so; but I have to disagree that the subject of the sentence needs to be the same, as the subject has  no bearing on the question.

Comment: *Assurance* can be uncountable in both meanings. From *Pride and Prejudice* (Jane Austen, 1813): "To Mr. Bennet's acknowledgments he briefly replied, with assurance of his eagerness to promote the welfare of any of his family." That has to be uncountable, because it's not *an assurance*. However, this meaning is relatively rare today, so *assurances* is the best answer, and I'm nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I believe it depends on whether "***their***" in the sentence is a singular or plural usage. If "their" is plural (in the sense of *they*), then "***assurances***" should be used. If "their" is singular (in the sense of *a company* for example), then "***assurance***" might be more appropriate. However, since "***all***" is used, "***multiple* *assurances*"** is probably implied either way. If that is the case then the plural form "***assurances***" is correct.

> Then suddenly, despite all **their** (*Joe's, Karen's, and Fred's*)
>   **assurances,** they broke the agreement.
>
> Then suddenly, despite all **their** (*a company sent them a letter*) **assurance**, they broke the
>   agreement.
>
> Then suddenly, after their third apologetic letter, despite **all their**
>   (*a company* sent them 3 letters) **assurances**, they broke the agreement.

Generally, you can treat it like any other noun. *If multiple assurances were given/received use the plural. If one assurance was given/received use the singular*.